# Java convert byte array to hex byte array

Tags: java, android, hex, decimal

I have a byte array that I want to convert its value in hexadecimal.

byte array = `[48, 48, 28, ...]`

--->

hex byte array = `[30, 30, 1C, ...]`

Comment: Here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java Just don't return a String of the array, but rather the converted array itself

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex byte array'. Hex is how you view it, print it, report it. Not a real question.

Comment: why is this tagged with android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Maybe you have to convert `byte` to `int` if its not casted implicitly.

```
String[] hexArray = new String[byteArray.length];
for(int index = 0; index < byteArray.length; index++) {
    hexArray[index] = Integer.toHexString(byteArray[index]);
    // maybe you have to convert your byte to int before this can be done
    // (cannot check reight now)
}
```

Comment: hexadecial is only the representation. an array of byte will always have value from 0 to 255 and not display as 00 to FF unless you convert it to a String representation like with the `Integer.toHexString()` method

Answer (score 1):

check [Integer.toHexString](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) method. iT will convert an int to a hex string. so iterate through your array and convert each number.